# Is there still needed to use View Holder pattern when using Data Binding?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-databinding, android-viewholder

I have a custom adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter<Item>`. Before trying to use Data Binding, I used this code and it worked fine:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Item item = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = createViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (item != null) {
        viewHolder.bindItem(item);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

But when I try to use Data Binding:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View rootView;
    Item item = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    int item = R.layout.item;
    ItemDataBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, item, parent, false);
    rootView = dataBinding.getRoot();
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(dataBinding);
    if (item != null) {
        viewHolder.bindItem(item);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Android Studio is complaining with the following warning:

> Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter.

Please see this [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/y61d5VC/Screenshot-2019-09-11-21-11-32.png).

When using Data Binding is also needed to use some like that? If yes, how? Thanks

Comment: if you have identified the problem, then please tell us the solution..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with listviews but I worked with Recyclerviews and the always worked fine. how about trying the recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your layout inflater

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```